# Setting SQL Variable via Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic-sql

I know I am overthinking this, but I've been banging against this for too long so I'm reaching out for help.

This is the statement I'm trying to run: `SELECT @cntMax = MAX(id) FROM [Raw_Item-FieldReport]`
BUT, the table name is a variable `@reportTable`

This doesn't work:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT @cntMax = MAX(id) FROM @reportTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I even tried having the actual table name in the `SET @sql` and that doesn't work either.
I didn't think it would be this difficult, please tell me I'm missing something easy/obvious.

Here's the full bit of code for those who want it:

```
DECLARE
    @inTable nvarchar(255) = 'Raw_Item',
    @reportTable nvarchar(255),
    @fieldName nvarchar(255),
    @cnt int,
    @cntMax int,
    @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @reportTable = @inTable + '-FieldReport'

SET @cnt = 1
SELECT @cntMax = MAX(id) FROM [Raw_Item-FieldReport]
PRINT @cntMax
SET @cntMax = 0

SET @sql = 'SELECT @cntMax = MAX(id) FROM [Raw_Item-FieldReport]'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
PRINT @cntMax
```

SQL Server 12.0.2008.8 (on Azure)

Comment: The dynamic table name is problematic for sure. You can't parameterize object names. You would have to create a string with the correct table name. This is very often a sign of some design issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an output parameter, otherwise SQL Server has no idea how to connect `@cntMax` in the dynamic SQL to `@cntMax` *not* in the dynamic SQL, since they are different scopes. And to protect yourself from SQL injection (some tips [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)), always check that your object exists, and use `QUOTENAME()` as opposed to manually adding square brackets (and you should always use `QUOTENAME()` when building object names from user input or variables, even when they don't have bad characters like dashes):

```
DECLARE @sql         nvarchar(max),
        @inTable     nvarchar(255) = N'Raw_Item',
        @reportTable nvarchar(255);

SET @reportTable = N'dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@inTable + '-FieldReport');

IF OBJECT_ID(@reportTable) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @sql = N'SELECT @cntMax = MAX(id) FROM ' + @reportTable + N';';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql,
           N'@cntMax int output', 
           @cntMax = @cntMax OUTPUT;

  PRINT @cntMax;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Nice try, h@xx0rs!';
END
```

[Always use schema reference](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) (`dbo`), [always use statement terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons), and please try to avoid naming things with invalid identifier characters like dash (`-`). And one additional tip: always use `N` prefix on `N'nvarchar string literals'`.

Comment: Thanks this worked great.  And thanks for the tips, I've incorporated them into the project :D